# Why did Kate say to Kevin "Maybe it'll happen"?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, home-alone

I've never understood why in "Home Alone" after Kevin says to his Mother (Kate) I wouldn't be sad if I woke up tomorrow morning and didn't have a Family, Kate says "Say it again, maybe it'll happen". Why did she say that? Was it planned or was she trying to say be careful what you wish for?

Comment: It's **absolutely clear** that leaving Kevin alone was an accident so obviously it was a case of being careful what you wish for.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of thing is not meant to be taken as a clue that something has been deliberate. The conversation is just a humorous example of [Forshadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreshadowing) a literary device where the writer hints what is to happen later in the story.